# Assign a shortcut to "Limit selection to visible" toggle

Tags: interface, customization

Where might this entry reside in the User Preferences > Input list? I would like to assign it to a key (using ver 2.69)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is not available by default in preferences but you can add it manually. Open your [user preferences](https://www.blender.org/manual/preferences/introduction.html#open-user-preferences) and go to the *Input* tab, toggle *3D View* and then *Mesh*.

[image]

Scroll to the bottom where you will see a button that says *Add new*. For the identifier, enter `wm.context_toggle` and for the *Context Attributes* enter `space_data.use_occlude_geometry`, next assign a key combination to it and save your user settings.

[image]

Comment: Nice! I was messing with that for a while.

Answer (score 0):

2.80 is still beta, but it doesn't hurt to know that for this advice to work is important to know that once you expand Mesh, you still need to expand the first entry too [Mesh (Global)]. Otherwise, you won't see that Add new button at the bottom.

Actually, after a closer inspection, the entries called "identifier", and "Context Attributes" are not found available.