# Why am I unable to delete vertices?

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices, selection-tools

I've got a ship model
[image]

For the purpose of a simplified collision model (My archers won't be running into the sails), I would like to remove all the sails, the rigging, and the strings. However, that does not seem to be possible.

Pressing X and going "Delete" leaves me with this:
[image]
And for some reason, the rigging won't go away.

Here's a quick GIF:

[image]

And here's a link to a less-jumpy MP4:
http://i.gyazo.com/ec063d07a527f86f592495dea173bb15.mp4

Even if I select a SINGLE VERTEX, it won't delete!

http://i.gyazo.com/a863b11ce9e9f01fcc4a77297983e2ce.mp4

How can I delete these vertices?

Comment: It's deleted all the vertices which are selected, but not all the vertices you want to select are getting selected. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5004/599

Comment: @gandalf3 You got this one?

Comment: @gandalf3 How do I select them all then? Even if I select a specific vertex, it still won't delete.

Comment: If @gandalf3 isn't answering, I can.

Comment: @Joehot200 Do the selecting in wireframe mode or with *Limit selection to visible* disabled.

Comment: Wire frame mode is unnecessary.

Comment: As @NoviceInDisguise says, Wireframe mode does seem fairly hefty for what I want. How do I do that other thing you mentioned?

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise What do you mean? Sure, there are other methods that might or might not work better. But it is the cause of the problem the OP is directly experiencing.

Comment: Wireframe mode hefty?? It's easier IMO to switch to wireframe with a tap of the Z key than to click the *Limit selection to visible icon*

Comment: @gandalf3 It's also just frozen blender. I think I'm going to have to restart, as it doesn't look like it's going to respond any time soon. Edit: Okay, now it's loaded, but it looks all weird. http://gyazo.com/d21a8724a74400d84e2442a6c41b748e - Also, it's still incredibly laggy.

Comment: ?? Something else must be going on, wireframe mode usually performs better than solid view.

Comment: In that screenshot it looks like you modified the mesh in some way.. (perhaps hit a key combo by accident?) Try reloading the file, then switching to wireframe.

Comment: @Joehot200 Wait a minute.. I don't mean actually creating a wireframe mesh with the modifier or wireframe tool, I mean using wire frame view (press `Z`). Just in case that was unclear. See the last part of my answer here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5005/599

Comment: @gandalf3 Sh*t. Sorry about that. I'm just an idiot who googles "Wireframe mode" instead of following instructions. Looks like my problem is now solved (it deletes successfully). Thank you so much!

Comment: Haha, no worries. Sorry about the confusion :P As your question is now answered, I'll vote to close this as a duplicate (I think the other posts has pretty much all the info I'd put in an answer here anyway)

Comment: @gandalf3 Would suggest answering here. That other question may have the same answer but the *question* is very different. See http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/549/duplicate-answer-vs-duplicate-question

Comment: @gandalf3 I thought you meant both at the same time

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise Both?

Comment: Wireframe and limit selection. BTW, you can set the limit selection button to a [hotkey](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7650/assign-a-shortcut-to-limit-selection-to-visible-toggle) if you want

Comment: @RayMairlot Hm.. Good point. Writing answer now.

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise Of course, but AFAIK there isn't one by default.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Blender *is* deleting all the selected vertices, but not all the vertices you want to delete are being selected.

This is because by default blender will not select vertices hidden behind other geometry when using a [selection tool like *Lasso* or *Box*](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5004/599). To select all geometry including vertices obscured behind other geometry, either perform the selecting in *Wireframe view* (<kbd>Z</kbd>):

[image]

Or turn off *Limit selection to visible* in *3D view > Header* to select obscured geometry in solid view:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Easy fix...
Turn on the X-ray and select them again. Now you'll be able to delete them.

Comment: How about a screenshot or two? A single sentence rarely makes a good answer when it comes to Blender. Look how much effort Gandalf put into his answer. That's quite a difference, compared to yours, right?