# How to apply shortcut to "Show whole scene transparent" ?

Tags: shortcut

How to apply shortcut for selecting invisible backside parts of mesh? 
It called "Limit Selection to Visible" option in 2.7

There was an answer for 2.7:
[Assign a shortcut to "Limit selection to visible" toggle](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7650/assign-a-shortcut-to-limit-selection-to-visible-toggle)
It doesnt work in 2.8

Answer (score 3):

Was looking for the same and just found it.

In **Blender 2.8** it is called *Toggle X-Ray* and the default shortcut is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.